# Учу react, когда пишу state выбивает ошибку и не могу понять почему... Помогите пожалуйста)

Tags: state

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as React from "react";
import Car from './Car/Car'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

    const [Cars, setCars] = useState([
        { name: "Ford", year: 2018 },
        { name: "Audi", year: 2016 },
        { name: "Mazda", year: 2010 }
    ]);

    const divStyle={
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
     const cars = this.state.cars
  return (
    <div style={divStyle}>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

        <Car name={'Ford'} year={2018}/>
        <Car name={'Audi'} year={2016}/>
        <Car name={'Mazda'} year={2010}/>
    </div>

  );
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    // return React.createElement(
    //     'div',
    //     {
    //         className: 'App'
    //     },
    //     React.createElement(
    //         'h1',
    //         null,
    //         'Hello world'
    //     )
    //
    // )

}

export default App;

И вот Car.js
import React from 'react'




// const car = () => {
//     return (
//         <div>This is car</div>
//     )
// }

// const car = () => (
//     <div>
//         This is car
//         <strong>test</strong>
//     </div>
// )



export default (props) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Car name: {props.name}</h3>
      <p>Year: <strong>{props.year}</strong></p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте хук `useState` в "stateless" компонентах.

Чтобы корректно работать с `this.state`, компонент должен наследовать класс `React.Component`.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import Car from './Car/Car';    

export default function App() {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([
    { name: "Ford", year: 2018 },
    { name: "Audi", year: 2016 },
    { name: "Mazda", year: 2010 }
  ]);

  const divStyle = {
    textAlign: "center"
  };

  return (
    <div style={divStyle}>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      { cars.map((car, i) => <Car key={i} name={car.name} year={car.year} />) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Только что попробывал, не помагает, все равно ошибка

Comment: Покажите свой код, также Car. У меня все работает - https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-sun-bg511?file=/src/App.js

Comment: А как его показать? Тут пишет превышение символов

Comment: Может это из-за того, что курсы по реакту, которые я прохожу 2020 года? И получается какая-то несовместимость?

Comment: Только что стер эту строчку "const сars = this.state.cars" и все стало нормально

Comment: <Car name={cars[0].name} year={cars[0].year}/> , когда пишу это теперь выбивает ошибку, не подскажете, что делать?

Comment: Не очень понял, как это не меняя Car?

Comment: @IgorKostyuk, функцию Car не меняйте, а остальное как у меня

Comment: Спасибо большое)